# Linux SIGINT passive capture

Tags: linux, logging, sigkill

Is there a place where the Linux kernel passively logs SIGKILL (kill -9) shutdown requests?

I have a JVM running that is arbitrarily being shut down and I suspect that, based on the evidence available, is being shut down by a stray process that is somehow issuing a shutdown of the JVM process. I have robust logging in place but in order to confirm my suspicion, I'd have to turn up the logging level to overwhelming levels.

I've researched exhaustively through /var/log and can't seem to find any place that might capture and log these SIGKILL events. Any ideas where I might find these events, if they exist?

Comment: SIGINT or SIGKILL? Anyway, I don't think there's any log of signals that are sent to processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:**

If your kernel has [ftrace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ftrace) support (very likely) try the `killsnoop` tool from Brendan Gregg's [perf-tools](https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools):

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brendangregg/perf-tools/master/killsnoop
chmod +x killsnoop
sudo ./killsnoop -s
```

More usage examples in the [killsnoop_example.txt](https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools/blob/master/examples/killsnoop_example.txt) file.

**Option 2: (passive capture)**

If your kernel has no ftrace support you can use the `kernel-siglog` kernel module from https://github.com/nfedera/kernel-siglog :

```
git clone https://github.com/nfedera/kernel-siglog.git

cd kernel-siglog/
make

sudo insmod siglog.ko
```

Once inserted the `siglog` kernel module will record the last 10,000 signals in `/proc/siglog`

I had a similar issue and found the culprit using this kernel module. I had it inserted on a customer's server for some weeks and when the service was killed I logged in, did a `cat /proc/siglog` and found that my service was killed by a customer's own buggy watchdog script.

Comment: Yep. This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks@

Comment: Glad I could help. However, no need of giving thanks in a comment, instead  you should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and act accordingly.